# Separate two validations with same redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new in Laravel4 world, and I'm trying to convert my site to laravel framework. But at beginning I have a little problem. On index I have two jquery modal: first for singin and second for registration. So, I want to when user try to login and make a mistake to show him an error. Same for registration. But when I have error in singin form, I get register form...My english is bad, so here is code:

routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
     return View::make("index.index");
}
Route::post('/', array('as'=> 'singin', function()
{
    $data = Input::all();
    $rules = array(
        'username' => 'min:3',
        'password' => 'min:6'
    );
    $validation = Validator::make($data, $rules);
    if($validation->passes())
    {
        return View::make('users.main');
    }
    Input::flash();

    return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors($validation);
}));
Route::post('/', array('as'=> 'register', function()
{
    // same as previous function
]
```

index.blade.php

```
<div id="signin" class="reveal-modal" @if($errors->all())
style="display:block; visibility:visible;" @endif >
    <header class="reveal-modal-header">
        Sign in
    </header>
    <div class="cont">

        <div class="indication">
            Sign In
        </div>
        {{ Form::open(array(
            'route' => 'singin',
            'class' => 'signin')) }}
        <p class="clearfix">
            {{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}
            {{ Form::text('username')}}
        </p>
        <p class="clearfix">

            {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}
            {{ Form::password('password')}}
        </p>
        <p class="without-label clearfix">
            {{ Form::submit('') }}
        </p>
        @if($errors->all())
        <div id="logindiverror" style="" class="alert alert-error">
        @foreach($errors->all('<li>:message</li>') as $message)
         {{ $message }}
        @endforeach
        </div>
        @endif

        {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal" id="close1" href="#">&#215;</a>
</div>

<div id="signup" class="reveal-modal" @if($errors->all())
style="display:block; visibility:visible;" @endif >>
    <header class="reveal-modal-header">
        Sign up
    </header>
    <div class="cont">
        <div class="indication">
            Register
        </div>
        {{ Form::open(array(
            'route' => 'register',
            'class' => 'signup')) }}

            <p class="clearfix">
                <em>(<abbr>*</abbr>) All fields are required</em>
            </p>
            <p class="clearfix">
                <label>Username:<abbr>*</abbr></label>
                {{ Form::text('username')}}
            </p>
            <p class="clearfix">
                <label>Email:<abbr>*</abbr></label>
                {{ Form::text('email') }}
            </p>
            <p class="clearfix">
                <label>Password:<abbr>*</abbr></label>
                {{ Form::password('password1'); }}
            </p>
            <p class="clearfix">
                <label>Password (repeat):<abbr>*</abbr></label>
                {{ Form::password('password2'); }}
            </p>

            <p class="checkboxes clearfix">
                <span class="niceCheck">{{ Form::checkbox('agree', '0') }}</span>
                I agree with LinkyPlanet Terms &amp; Privacy Policy
            </p>
        <p class="without-label clearfix">
            {{ Form::submit('') }}
        </p>

        @if($errors->all())
        <div id="logindiverror" style="" class="alert alert-error">
            @foreach($errors->all('<li>:message</li>') as $message)
            {{ $message }}
            @endforeach
        </div>
        @endif

        {{ Form::close() }}

    </div>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal" id="close2" href="#">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

So, problem is when user try to sing in, and he make a mistake in password (pass is shorter than 6 chars), script redirect him to index and open modal for registration and there show an error, not in sing in modal. Where is mistake?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have 2 "different" routes using the same URI (`/`) and the same method (`POST`), but you cannot.

Only the first one will work, by precedence. Something like this could be better:

```
Route::post('/singin', array('as'=> 'singin', function()
{

}));

Route::post('/register', array('as'=> 'register', function()
{

}));
```

Or you can keep one of them on `/` and change the other one:

```
Route::post('/', array('as'=> 'singin', function()
{

}));

Route::post('/register', array('as'=> 'register', function()
{

}));
```

**EDIT:**

You are using the same name for everything ($errors in register and sign in). If you have ONE view for both, you need to have different names. You can use

```
return Redirect::to('/')->with('registerErrors', $validation->messages());
```

and

```
return Redirect::to('/')->with('signInErrors', $validation->messages());
```

But on tedirects they are bound to your session, so you'll have to get them this way:

```
@if(Session::has('registerErrors'))
    <div id="logindiverror" style="" class="alert alert-error">
        @foreach(Session::get('registerErrors')->all('<li>:message</li>') as $message)
            {{ $message }}
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: No...I'm getting same problem again...IS there a way to somehow know from what validator I'm getting an error?

Comment: I misunderstood your problem. Edited.

Comment: Antonio, I'm still have same problem. I think that problem is in index.blade.php file in IF conditions. Script check if exist $error variable, and after false validation $error variable exist for signin and register modal. Is there a better way, or some way to indetify from which route I'm getting validation error?

Comment: I didn't try that yet, but I think it's work :) Thanks Antonio